How to use Microsoft Graph SDK in Blazor .NET 8 web app
I have to use the Microsoft Graph SDK in a Blazor web app on .NET 8, but it doesn't seem implemented yet, is there a working example?
I'm trying on Visual Studio 2022 with packages Microsoft.Graph 5.58.0 and Microsoft.Graph.Core 3.1.21

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Could you please share the render mode you are using in your blazor web app? Server side rendered or Auto render?

For blazor web app interactive server render mode application, we can use codes below to integrate Azure AD and Graph SDK，then we can inject GraphServiceClient into the component like @using Microsoft.Graph @inject GraphServiceClient GraphClient
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddMicrosoftGraph()
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

My test sample has nuget packages below.
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="8.0.0" NoWarn="NU1605" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="8.0.0" NoWarn="NU1605" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="5.56.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph.Core" Version="3.1.17" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="3.1.0" />
</ItemGroup>

The sample above requires users to sign in first so that the Graph Client can get authorized and call Graph API. If you don't want a sign-in step, then you could learn about Azure Ad client credential flow. And this requires us to consent Application type permission. And you can use codes below in your component.
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenantId";
var clientId = "clientId";
var clientSecret = "clientSecret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var res = await graphClient.Users.GetAsync();

